# NMinimize calling an own defined function

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I want to call an own defined function through `NMinimize`. For the sake of simplicity, let us define the problem as follow:

```
radpatt[x1_] :=
   (Print[x1];
   x1
   )

NMinimize[{radpatt[xx], 0.1 <= xx <= 1.1}, {xx}]
```

If you run the above-listed instructions, you will notice that `x1` is not number as soon as the function `radpatt` is called by `NMinimize`, but it is equal to `xx`. This causes me an issue because in my original problem `x1` needs to be a number just at the beginning of my own function. Any ideas?

Many many thanks in advance.

Comment: `radpatt[x1_?NumericQ]` to restrict it to numerical arguments only.

Comment: See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26037/4999